# Preventing L-value instantiation in C++14

Tags: c++, c++14

Methods in C++14 can tell whether they're called on an L-value or an R-value:

```
struct A{
  A() { puts("Ctor"); }
  void m() const & { puts("L-value"); }
  void m() const && { puts("R-value"); }
};

int main(){
  A a; //Ctor
  a.m() //L-value
  A().m(); //Ctor; R-value
}
```

Can a ctor tell which type it's constructing?
Can I completely disable the construction of L-values from my class?

I have a proxy class (several, actually), which should always convert to something else. Using it without converting is an error. I can detect that error at runtime, e.g., by adding a `bool used_ = 0;` member `#ifndef NDEBUG;` and setting it in my user-specified cast, and then doing `assert(used_)` in the proxy class's `Dtor`, however it would be much nicer if I could get to compiler to prevent instatiation of `L-value` instances of that proxy in the first place:

```
 auto x = Proxy().method1().method2(); // no
 Proxy p; // no
 Target x = Proxy(); //yes
 Target x = Proxy().method1().method2(); //yes
```

Can I do something like that with C++14?

Comment: The old-school way to achieve what you want is to set the constructor to private and allow construction only through static methods. I think that would also be more intuitive to the person working with your code.

Comment: `auto&& x = Proxy();` cannot be prevented IIRC. And then `x` is a modifiable lvalue Proxy.

Comment: I have a feeling the answer is still no and you have to do what ypnos suggests

Comment: This might be impossible :( in C++17 because `auto x = f()` can created an `x` without invoking or depending semantically in any copy or move constructor. If you ask me, I would say this is a defect of C++17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why, of course:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B;

class A
{
public:
    A(B&& b) {}

    A(const B&) = delete;
};

class B {};

int main()
{
    B b;

    // A a1; <- error
    // A a2 = b; // <- error
    A a3 = move(b); // <- fine

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As far as I understood `A a3 = move(b);` is not supposed to compile because `a3` is an lvalue.

Comment: In that case the code snippet does not help at all, right

Comment: Thanks. Will use this. It's close enough.

Answer (score 4):

```
struct temporary_only {
  static temporary_only make() { return {}; }
  temporary_only(temporary_only&&)=delete;
  int get()&& { return 3; }
private:
  temporary_only() {}
};

int main() {
  //temporary_only x; // illegal
  std::cout << temporary_only::make().get() << '\n'; // legal
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a88b16bddfd5d7c5).

We disable all public ctors (including copy/move), so nobody can create a `temporary_only` except via `temporary_only::make` (an rvalue).

Note that

```
temporary_only&& a = temporary_only::make();
```

still works.  Here we have an rvalue bound to an rvalue reference, and that rvalue reference is itself an lvalue with a multi-line lifetime (scope lifetime).  This cannot be stopped.

Comment: Also `const temporary_only& a = temporary_only::make();` works as well

Comment: And to make matters worse `std::move(a).get()` also works just fine.

Comment: I have been looking for a solution to this problem for a long time, unfortunately, this trick doesn't work in C++17 as it did in C++14, https://godbolt.org/z/4dn16f16o

Comment: The standard could have prevented this syntax `auto a = = temporary_only::make()` as a provision if the copy/move constructor was marked `explicit`.

Comment: @alfC I think explicit copy/move ctor has no other meaning in C++.  I could imagine making it mean "do not elide".  Might be worth proposing.

Comment: Yes, I was proposing to make-it-mean/recycle-the-keyword. But it makes sense because `explicit` typically prevents the syntax `T self  = other;` (and forces `T self{other};`), so it could do the same for `auto self = other;` (the syntax `auto self{other};` might still work but it is sufficiently "explicit" such that I have no issue with it)